# How can i categorize a post using checkbox in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to categorize a post using check box e.g a post that is related to sports, user shall categorize it as a sport. so how can i do this in Laravel? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about Laravel. I suggest using a form that only have the checkbox with the categories, and when the user check any of the options, send it to a controller and then store in a database.

For example:

```
<form action="/ruta-a-tu-controlador" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Sports"> Sports
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="Money">Money
</form>
```

And in your controller you recieve it with request.

```
public function MyController(Request $request){
  $request->all();
  /* Save it to your database */
}
```

If you give us more information, we can help you. Have you tried something? Any ideas? Is better try and then ask.